# Personal accounting software that supports both split and joint accounts well? (Also, forecasts.)

Tags: finance

I've been using [Mint](http://www.mintaccounting.co.uk/) for a little while, and I like it enough that I want to convince my wife to jump on board.

From what I've seen, though, there's no good way to have keep track of accounts where the asset/liability is shared.

Let me be specific. We have a shared credit card and a shared savings account, but our paychecks come to our personal checking accounts. Monthly, we both pay half of the CC. There's no way to say "half of this debt is mine" except for splitting every single transaction. Therefore, there's no way to calculate our individual net worth and things like that.

Basically I guess the problem is with their data model, that one login represents one legal person. There's lots of feature requests for this sort of thing, but I don't expect it to happen any time soon.

Bonus feature: forecasts. I want to be able to define a bunch of recurring transactions and then ask what my various balances will be at some point in the future, assuming some interest rate.

Answer (score 1):

To share costs, I use [Splitwise](https://www.splitwise.com), which comes in (linked, cloud based) mobile and web app form. I find the production value of the app and the UX sublime. However, it's not a fully fledged accounting app, it's mostly for tracking shared expenses. I use it with my flatmate, my friends and my girlfriends, and even though it doesn't have smart reciept scanning technology, I find it so easy to use and add expenses quickly. I don't work for them, I promise!

The downside is that it's not a fully fledged personal accountancy app, or at least I have never used it as one, and so while you can export your expenses in CSVs etc, I'm not sure it would directly fill your needs.

Sorry I can't help any more! Did you find your own solution in the meantime?

Comment: I don't think Splitwise is quite right. I'm able to split the CC bill fine. With Mint, it's just that my net worth includes this debt entirely, not half.